# How to bind a data to gridview using MVP design pattern

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-access-layer, mvp, telerik-grid

Please Can i know is their any good article which describes the complete flow of how to bind a gridview using MVP design pattern.

Comment: i think he clearly says he means MVP Pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this in [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381661/how-to-bind-data-and-manipulate-it-in-a-gridview-with-mvp)

[this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ModelViewPresenter.aspx) is pretty good on the details of the mvp pattern. you can apply the concept in your gridview instance.

Comment: Thanks for that , I want a article which describes each step part by part , so that i can visualize the complete flow.